# LinkedIn API credentials

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am looking to use the LinkedIn Developer API and struggling to figure out where to find some of the credentials.

In particular I need

CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN, and USER_SECRET.

I have created an application and got my client ID and client secret but what about the other two?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consumer_Key and Consumer_secret are used by your app to authenticate with LinkedIn, while the User_Token and User_Secret are used to authorize a LinkedIn User with your app. [Linkedin OAuth2 docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) The docs will explain how to receive the user_token and user_secret.

--Update--
Authentication docs have been moved to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

Comment: The link no longer works. Searching for this information in the LinkedIn Developer help centre returns a lot of pages without the actual information. Did you mean [this page](https://oauth.net/2/)?